# What do red colored tags indicate

Tags: support

I'm curious to find learn what red colored tags indicate, for example, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Does this mean the tag is marked for deletion? How does a tag become red in the first place?

Comment: Because of context I think it is just to make them stand out as a tag to show that a feature request or bug report has been fixed so that the question has been completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work)

> **Moderator-only Tags**
>
> These tags can only be applied and removed by diamond moderators. They appear in red, not the usual gray, and confer a degree of official status.